# Android phone specs comparison site?

Tags: discussion

I am not sure if this is off-topic for the main site. Am I allowed to ask it there?

I am shopping for a new Android and would like a web site where I can do side by side comparisons, especially if I can start by entering my preferred spec. I can't seem to find one my Googling.

Comment: I don't know if this has occured to the moderators here. Under the guise of asking whether a question is allowed on the main site, he has formulated that question HERE instead. Is that the proper procedure now? Are we creating slide-questions-in-through-META precedent?

Comment: @wbogacz some SEs do that.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your question has been asked before and is a duplicate of [How can I find the comparison of specs and features of Android devices?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/770/where-can-i-find-a-comparison-of-android-devices).

As per the "general recommendation" close reason, asking for finding off-site resources is generally discouraged:

> Questions asking us to **find or recommend an app, device, ROM, accessory or *off-site resource*** are off-topic for Android Enthusiasts as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam and become obsolete quickly. [Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve.](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping)

<sup>(Italic emphasis added to the original bold emphasis)</sup>

However, I can see that the core topic of "comparing device specs" itself may be useful to many.

I've reworded and reopened the linked question, though it is currently wiki-locked, so anyone can still contribute to that Q&A by editing it.