# Why was my answer about Android phone specs comparison site deleted?

Tags: discussion, moderation

Someone asked: [Android phone specs comparison site?](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2695/12202)

I answered the following, but it was deleted by a mod. Why?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I deleted the answer precisely because of [the comment on the question](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2695/android-phone-specs-comparison-site#comment7013_2695):

> [...] Under the guise of asking whether a question is allowed on the main site, he has formulated that question HERE instead. [...] Are we creating slide-questions-in-through-META precedent?

The linked question was asking whether such a question is on-topic or not. There's actually no problem with the meta question since providing a sample question can clarify what the discussion is about.

As per [What's Meta?](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta),

> Meta Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange is the part of the site where users discuss the workings and policies of Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange rather than discussing Android itself. It is separated from the main Q&A to reduce noise there while providing a legitimate space for people to ask how and why this site works the way it does.

However, instead of providing arguments for the premise of the discussion, *the answer in the question directly answered the sample question*. **This is giving a bad precedent where users may get the wrong idea that there is a loophole to use meta sites to ask any Android questions that are not allowed on the main site.**

---

I noticed [your comment reply](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2695/android-phone-specs-comparison-site#comment7014_2695) on there:

> some SEs do that.

While I also noticed that some SE sites do that (e.g. learning/resource recommendation on child meta), note that *this community hasn't had any discussion and decision on whether such questions are allowed or not on the meta.*

The only exceptional case that I know of is [Where can I ask questions that aren't Android Enthusiast questions?](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/371/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-arent-android-enthusiast-questions), but that is more for moderation purposes (linked from the closed post notice banner).

Comment: Thanks, then why not answering that to their question? Just deleting my answer doesn't help at all.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt apologize for the lack of info, I was in a bit hurry at that time. I've revisited the meta discussion and posted an answer there.